# I cannot run React Native app on expo environment on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I cannot run React Native app on expo environment on Android; it throws this error when running the app on Expo on my Android phone:

```
Something went wrong.
32.0.0 is not a valid sdk version. Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0, 33.0.0, UNVERSIONED.
```

Same app works perfectly on Expo environment on my iOS phone.

I launch 'expo start' from my MAC and connect both phones to the same WIFI as my MACBOOK PRO.

Here is my app.json file :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "travel-management-app",
    "slug": "travel-management-app",
    "description": "Travel management application",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
    "icon": "./assets/icons/bg_screen5_square.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/icons/bg_screen5.png"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "travel-management-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Travel management Application",
  "author": "Luchian Chivoiu",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://www.sienna.ro",
  "main": "src/index.native.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^3.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-art": "^16.8.3",
    "react-autowhatever": "^10.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.17",
    "react-native-gesture-handler-web": "npm:react-native-gesture-handler@1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.3",
    "react-native-ratings": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-touchable-scale": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.10.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.5.1",
    "react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.2.1",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "web": "react-app-rewired start",
    "native": "expo start",
    "build:web": "react-app-rewired build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build:android": "expo ba",
    "build:ios": "expo bi",
    "eject:web": "react-scripts eject",
    "eject:native": "expo eject",
    "prettify": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.js'",
    "clean-install": "rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && watchman watch-del-all && yarn"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "customize-cra": "^0.2.12",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

package-lock.json contains this:

```
"react-native": {
      "version": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+taJh7bN2owmwaZpJUrNpHdmPAL6ZynNCZj15uLQgjaPFq0ZBIG2ZWuSJ48eGoUjAb3lrWxkmLlHb2eJFXc7sQ==",
```

How can I make this work on Android too? This app worked on expo on my Android phone some days ago until I did some package update.

I have updated something, some package , a package and maybe that made this Android expo app not able to run.

Comment: Hi what version of expo client are you using on your android phone?

Comment: I deleted and installed again the expo client on my android application so I assume is the last one, I am going to check now what version

Comment: I also updated my android OS system on my phone so it should be the last one

Comment: version 2.13.0 is the version of my expo client on my android phone

Comment: That looks ok Delete your node modules folder and run `yarn install` or `npm install` depending on which one you use.

Comment: i did that too and it is still the same

Comment: i will try again now

Comment: Your expo client is updated and minimum sdk must be 33 or higher.. you can look at Dropping SDKs 31 and 32 from the Expo client: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4 read: Upgrading Your App

Comment: if I change the 32 to 33 manually in the config files it still throws another error

Comment: that the react libraries are not corresponding as a version with other libraries

Comment: I am doing yarn install or npm install right now

Comment: @Oleg yes, i think you are right, they are dropping the 31 and 32 version, so it is pointless to continue with them, i will try to upgrade to 35

Comment: @Oleg post your last comment as an answer, as this was the solution, I followed the steps from  blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4  Upgrading Your App and it all worked. I had some issues, upgrading some deprecated imports as : deprecated form of importing , now updated to these forms : import * as Font from "expo-font" and import {activateKeepAwake} from "expo-keep-awake"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an outdated Expo SDK and applications, SDK 32 and below is no longer maintained.

Follow the instructions on this [link](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4) you should be good to go

Hope this Helps!